# 'Search more' view in a many2one field from list view to kanban view in OpenERP

Tags: javascript, odoo, many-to-one

The 'Search more...' option in a many2one field in OpenERP shows the list view. How can i change it to kanban view? Now the code is like this.

```
 // search more... if more results that max
        if (values.length > self.limit) {
            values = values.slice(0, self.limit);
            values.push({
                label: _t("Search More..."),
                action: function() {
                    dataset.name_search(search_val, self.build_domain(), 'ilike', 160).done(function(data) {
                        self._search_create_popup("search", data);
                    });
                },
                classname: 'oe_m2o_dropdown_option'
            });
        }
```

Comment: Not clearly what you are saying. need some proper explanation.

Comment: @user1153551.. in a many2one field, if you type anything there are 3 options. Search More,Create, Create and Edit. If you select the 'search more' option , you can get a tree view of all possible values. But i need kanban view on selecting 'search more'. Hope you understood. Thanks,

Comment: thank you for reply me. you mean you have to use this field only kanban view.

Comment: i need to show kanban view on 'search more'.